# How to extract text from a file which appears one or more times in each line?

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file which have 1 or more email ids in each line. E.g.

```
id:123, name:test, id: 5678, name john, address:new york  
id:567, name:bob  
id:3643, name:meg, id: 6721, name kate, address:la
```

Now, the problem is id:value may appear one or more times in a single line. How do I extract all id:value pairs so that the output is,

```
id:123, id:5678  
id:567  
id:3643, id:6721
```

I tried `egrep -o` but that is putting each `id:value` pair in a separate line.

`sed/awk` should do the trick but I am a noob

Do not want to use `Perl` as that will require a Perl installation.

**EDIT:**
On further analysis of the data files, I am seeing inconsistent separators, i.e. not all lines are `,` separated. Some are even separated with `:` and `|`. Also, `,` is appearing within the address value field. i.e. `address:52nd st, new york`. Can this be done in `awk` using a regex expression?

Answer (score 2):

If your content is in the file `test.txt` then the following command:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/ *: */:/g' | grep -o 'id:[0-9]*'
```

will return:

```
id:123
id:5678
id:567
id:3643
id:6721
```

The sed command is to remove any spaces adjacent to the colon, yielding an output of:

```
id:123, name:test, id:5678, name john, address:new york
id:567, name:bob
id:3643, name:meg, id:6721, name kate, address:la
```

and the `grep -o` command finds all matches to `id:` proceeded by zero or more numbers, with the `-o` to return only the matching part of the input string.

Per the man page:

```
-o, --only-matching    Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching 
                       line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

(FYI, the grep and sed commands are using regular expressions.)

**EDIT:**
   Sorry, I didn't read carefully.  I see that you object to the `-o` output format of one value per line.  Back to the drawing board...

Note:  If the reason you are opposed to the `-o` output is to preserve line numbers, using `grep -no` will give the following output (where the first number is the line number):

```
1:id:123
1:id:5678
2:id:567
3:id:3643
3:id:6721
```

Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\<id:\s*/\n/g;s/,[^\n]*//g;s/\n/, id:/g;s/^, //' file
```

Convert the words `id:` and any following spaces to a unique token (in this case `\n`). Delete anyting following a `,` upto a `\n`. Replace the `\n` by the token `, id:` and then delete the leading `,`.

Comment: I tried some hours to get this working, but without result. I have to learn much more. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 awk -F, '{id=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/id:/) id=id?id FS $i:$i; print id}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
id:123, name:test, id: 5678, name john, address:new york  
id:567, name:bob  
id:3643, name:meg, id: 6721, name kate, address:la  

$ awk -F, '{id=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/id:/) id=id?id FS $i:$i; print id}' file
id:123, id: 5678
id:567
id:3643, id: 6721
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/id:[^,]*/g;print "@a";undef @a' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
id:123, name:test, id: 5678, name john, address:new york  
id:567, name:bob  
id:3643, name:meg, id: 6721, name kate, address:la  
> perl -lne 'push @a,/id:[^,]*/g;print "@a";undef @a' temp
id:123 id: 5678
id:567
id:3643 id: 6721
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation of an answer allready given..I personaly prefere the script verion in a file more than the command line    (better control, readability)

id.txt

```
id:1, name:test, id:2, name john, address:new york  
id:3, name:bob  
id:4, name:meg, id:5, name kate, address:la
```

id.akw

```
{
i=0
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{ if($i~/id:/)
id=id?id $i:$i;}
print id
id=""
}
```

call: awk -f id.awk id.txt
output:

```
id:1, id:2,
id:3,
id:4, id:5,
```